# How to set visibility of html element in html

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

if there is a visualforce element then we set visibility according to the redered attribute .
=but i have to set visibility of visualforce according to data of html element

```
    <p style="display:{! IF(userSettings == null && $Profile.Name !='System Administrator','visible','hidden')}">Click on the authorize to authorize your self to Google GLASS Account &nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Authorize" action="{! authorizeApp}"  />
```

i want to set visibility but its showing me the p element in every case.please guideline how to do this ??

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the html with outputpanel and use rendered attribute to conditionally display or hide